# Check if turbolinks has a cache to determine when to display a loading spinner

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm working on rails project in which I'm using turbolinks.

When a user clicks a link, I'd like to be able to check if Turbolinks has a cache for the page the user is going to. If it's not cached, I'd like to display a loading spinner.

I've checked the docs and looked into the data on the different Turbolinks events, but I haven't been able to find a way to do this.

Is there a way I can do this check?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I ask why you might want to do this?

Comment: When turbolinks doesn't have a cache I want to show a spinner to give the user some feedback while the page is loading. I've found out how to do this now though.

Comment: @user2320239 care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found using `Turbolinks.controller.cache.snapshots` gives a list of all cache snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* dig around in the `Turbolinks.controller` cache, but given that it's not documented, there's no guarantee it will always be there (e.g. in the next version). A more idiomatic approach might be as follows:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:click', function () {
  showSpinner()
})

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function () {
  hideSpinner()
})
```

`turbolinks:load` for a cached page happens immediately, so the spinner will not be visible.